# Kickstart %ksappend Filepath

Tags: filesystems, kickstart

I'm trying to modularize my kickstart file; in particular, I'd like the %pre section to live in a separate file brought in using the %ksappend statement. However, this consistently fails with the installer saying '/run/install/ks.cfg is missing'; I'll note that my actual kickstart file is called ks_system.cfg, so I assume the ks.cfg being asked for is the one that results from initial parsing of the kickstart file. %ks_append is definitely the cause here; removing it gets rid of the error - but of course I don't have my pre-file included if I do that, and must include its contents directly in the master kickstart file.

I can't find any documentation on how to reference this file during the initial processing phase. The intent is to include it in the installation ISO file alongside the other kickstart files - the master ks_system.cfg, and other components that are successfully included using %include statements after pre-processing has finished.

I've tried as many variations of the file path I can think of but continue receiving this failure. How do I reference a file alongside the master ks_system.cfg kickstart file in the ISO with %ksappend?